# Need to create a text file from output

Tags: php

I have a text file, I need to read it and  to format it in different manner and to create a new file.

New File should look like this and old file is just a list of numbers, basically I need to add more data for each entry and create a new formatted list like below

```
Initialize
ENM.ALPHA
ENM.BETA
018327363
2

Initialize
ENM.ALPHA
ENM.BETA
0183344555
2
.
.
```

and so on 
Following is the code I am using, it creates a file but does not format it as I want. It creates new file but  in 1 line and `<br/>` is also there in the output. How can I format it as above? How can I remove html tag from new file but get my desired format

```
   $ob_file = fopen('test11.txt','w');
    function ob_file_callback($buffer)
      {
        global $ob_file;
        fwrite($ob_file,$buffer);
      }
     $ob_file = fopen('test11.txt','w');
     //Anything we output now will go to test.txt
     ob_start('ob_file_callback');
     foreach ($s as $d1){
    echo strip_tags("di" ."<br/>" );
     echo "ENM.ALPHA" .'<br/>' ;
     echo "ENM.BETA" .'<br/>' ;
     echo "0183344555" .'<br/>' ;
      echo $d1 .'<br/>' ;
     echo '2' .'<br/>'.PHP_EOL ;
     echo "\r\n" .'<br/>';
     echo "\r\n" .'<br/>';

     }
    ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Why are you using output buffering instead just calling `fwrite()` directly? And why do you open the file twice?

Comment: You shouldn't put `<br/>` in text files, that's for HTML. Use `PHP_EOL` in plain text file.

Comment: You don't need to remove tags if you don't put them in there in the first place.

Comment: Do you want to write to a new file or just display the text in browser without html-tags in source code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application to use a [here-doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
$file = fopen("test11.txt", "w");
foreach ($s as $d1) {
    $block = <<<EOS
    Initialize
    ENM.ALPHA
    ENM.BETA
    $d1
    2

    EOS;
    fwrite($file, $block);
}
fclose($file);
```

You don't need to put `<br/>` in text files. That's an HTML tag.

Comment: it worked, but it had put just one block to file, does not iterate through whole file.